# How do you delete untracked local files

Tags: git

I can't delete untracked files from git.

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .atom/
        .bash_history
        .config/
        .quokka/
        .vscode/
        3D Objects/
        AppData/
        Contacts/
        Desktop/
        Documents/
        Downloads/
        Favorites/
        Links/
        MicrosoftEdgeBackups/
        Music/
        NTUSER.DAT
        NTUSER.DAT{fd9a35db-49fe-11e9-aa2c-248a07783950}.TM.blf
        NTUSER.DAT{fd9a35db-49fe-11e9-aa2c-248a07783950}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms
        NTUSER.DAT{fd9a35db-49fe-11e9-aa2c-248a07783950}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms
        OneDrive/
        Pictures/
        Saved Games/
        Searches/
        Videos/
        ntuser.dat.LOG1
        ntuser.dat.LOG2
        ntuser.ini

Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue.
```

Comment: It looks like you've turned your home directory into a Git repository. Is that what you meant to do? I suspect it's a mistake.

Comment: Yeah. what do i have to do

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please give us some context.

Comment: I want to clean local (untracked).

Comment: try `git clean`

Comment: i have tried...

Comment: when i try clean:  warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Application Data/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/History/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/INetCache/Content.IE5/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Temporary Internet Files/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'AppData/Local/Temp/CR_49A1F.tmp/': Permission denied

Comment: What do you mean by "delete them from git"? They're not *in* git--they're untracked. Just delete the `.git` directory if you've done this by mistake (which I would assume is the case--if not, add them to your `.gitignore`). You almost *certainly* do not want your home directory under git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *untracked file* is a file that is not in Git's *index*, and therefore will not be in the *next* commit you make.

To remove such a file, you simply remove the file, using your regular operating system's file-remover.  **When you do this, unless your OS has a file-restoring operation, the file is gone forever.**  Git will not be able to get it back for you.

(Note that whether or not a file is tracked, that doesn't change any existing *commits* in the existing Git repository.  But what you're doing right now seems incredibly dangerous: you're going to delete all your files irrecoverably.)